# Matrix Proof $(kA)^n = k^n \cdot A^n$

Tags: matrices, proof-writing

I have to prove the f.f.g:

If $A$ is an invertible matrix and $k$ is any non-zero scalar then

$$
    (kA)^n = k^n \cdot A^n
$$
I want to know how to go about starting this, I opted to use Mathematical Induction is this correct:

I started with:

Prove is True for $n = 1$:
$$
(kA)^{1} = (kA) = kA
$$
$$
k^{1} \cdot A^{1} = kA
$$
Hence statement holds for $n = 1$. I just want to know if this is the correct path.

Also I want to know sometimes when people represent matrices the use e.g $A$, but at other times they use $A_{ij}$. Why? I know that $i$ refers to number of rows and $j$ refers to number of coloumns .

I also see this:
$$
A_{ij} = [a_{ij}]
$$
What does this mean?

Is this correct notation:
$$
(cA)_{ij} = ca_{ij}
$$
What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are halfway there. Knowing that for $n=1$ it holds, if for some $m$:
$$(kA)^m=k^m\cdot A^m$$
then you only need to show
$$(kA)^{m+1}=k^{m+1}\cdot A^{m+1}$$
which seems straightforward, since the product of a matrix with a scalar is commutative (i.e. $\alpha A=A\alpha$)
$$(kA)^{m+1}=(kA)^{m}\cdot (kA)=(k^m\cdot A^m)\cdot k\cdot A=k^{m+1}\cdot A^mA=k^{m+1}\cdot A^{m+1}$$
About the second part of your question, [you can refer to this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Notation).